# populate xml files with data from csv file

Tags: xml, csv

I have two files; a csv file with my data and a template .xml file. I'm trying to create a new .xml file for each row of the csv, name the new file with the data from the first column and then populate it with the remaining data in that row

So my csv looks like this

```
heading1,heading2,heading3,heading4
data1,data2,data3,data4
data1a,data2a,data3a,data4a
```

And I'm trying to make two xml files which looks like this

filename data1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentMetaData>
  <ContentType>CustomFile</ContentType>
  <ContentName>Data2</ContentName>
  <Fields>
    <Ref><![CDATA[data3]]></Ref>
    <Description><![CDATA[data4]]></Description
```

filename data1a.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ContentMetaData>
      <ContentType>CustomFile</ContentType>
      <ContentName>data2a</ContentName>
      <Fields>
        <Ref><![CDATA[data3a]]></Ref>
        <Description><![CDATA[data4a]]></Description
```

Ideally I'd like a script as I'll have to do this quite a lot as people pass me the populated csv files. Any help at all is really appreciated!

Thanks very much!

Comment: Show us your effort please. Have you tried anything in any language at all so far?

Comment: Hi, thanks, I've not got anything really! i'm trying to piece togethor things from various other posts at the moment

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the simple steps:

1. Read the CSV file line by line using any File Reading API
2. Create a method in java/C++ which converts the csv string into the XML string, you just need to write it as simple string the XML format you want.
   e.g. in java:

   StringBuffer sbtag = new StringBuffer();
   sbtag.append("");

   ..........

   ......
3. Keep writing the tags in the ouptut xml file.